# Infinitive form for past event

Tags: verbes, temps-grammatical, infinitif

> (a) C'était bon de me détendre pendant les vacances.
>
> (b) C'était bon de m'être détendu(e) pendant les vacances.

Which sentence is correct? Since we are talking about the vacation which is in the past, I think (b) should be more correct. But I'm not sure if (a) is correct as well.

What about

> (c) C'est bon de finir mon travail.
>
> (d) C'est bon d'avoir fini mon travail.

Comment: a) is the right answer.  b) includes "imparfait" and "passé compose" in the same sentence which makes it really confusing overall.

Comment: @12Lapointep Thanks. Would it be correct to say "C'**est** bon de m'être détendu(e) pendant les vacances."?

Comment: I would put C'est in past tense right away to shy away from any confusion it might cause by reading your sentence.  Therefore, the second verb would be in the present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) is right.

(b) is less idiomatic; it looks like a past in the past.

(c) should be *C'est bon de finir **son** travail.*

(d) ditto: should be *C'est bon d'avoir fini **son** travail.*

Comment: Would it be idiomatic to say "C'**est** bon de m'être détendu(e) pendant les vacances."?

Comment: Also what do you think about the sentences (c) and (d) I just added?

Comment: Answer added. (c) and (d) are fine when turned into generic statements.

Comment: Why can't I use "mon" in (c) and (d) if I only want to talk about myself rather than make a generic statement?

Comment: Because "C'est bon" is generic. Note that if you say *c'est bon d'avoir fini son travail* when finishing your work, everyone understand you are talking about yourself. Alternatively: *Je suis content d'avoir fini mon travail.*

Comment: Then wouldn't sentence (a) be wrong for this reason as well?

Comment: No, *c'était bon* is not generic but introducing something real that happened.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jiliagre: the second feels like your vacations were before another event to which "c'etait" would be attached. In terms of style, "je me suis bien detendu pendant les vacances" is more direct and about equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be correct to say "C'**est** bon de m'être détendu(e) pendant les vacances."?

Comment: It feels somewhat strange, I wouldn't say it naturally. If you wanted to use "C'est bon", it would have to be "C'est bon de **se** detendre pendant les vacances": take out the "m'", and it becomes less personal. It's more like a general statement. "C'est bon de s'etre detendu" (past) IMHO doesn't work either. I think this past tense would introduce something specific as jiliagre points to below. Note also how jiliagre also says "c'est bon" is generic. Same feeling for me.